# Why this polynomial represents this figure?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to understand why this figure is represented by this polynomial expression:

[image]

My goal is to prove directly why cartesian product of natural numbers is equinumerous to the natural numbers. I've already checked to the first elements of $(m,n)$ and indeed this polynomial seems to represent this figure.

I'm having problems to see why this figure is represented by this polynomial expression.

Thanks

Comment: The polynomial is not needed to understand why the rationals are countable. Most proofs don't bother giving the polynomial formula, its a bit of a distraction. All you have to believe/understand is that if you keep drawing these diagonal arrows every rational number will be on at least one diagonal line. That allows you to produce a list of numbers which includes every rational number/

Comment: Are you familiar with the triangular numbers, $T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: @pjs36 no, do you have some suggestion to use it in this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it as
$$
J(m,n)=T(m+n)+m
$$
where $T(m+n)$ denotes the number of points in the triangle below the line $x+y=m+n$ equivalent to $y=-x+(m+n)$. Then $m$ counts how many *steps* we have taken away from the $y$-axis on that line. Here is an example:

[image]

---

Here $T(k)$ is a well known function returning the $k$-th [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):
$$
\begin{align}
T(k)&=0+1+...+k\\
&=\tfrac12[(0+k)+(1+k-1)+...+(k+0)]\\
&=\tfrac12k(k+1)
\end{align}
$$

---

BTW, the inverse function of $J(m,n)=i$ is $K(i)=(m(i),n(i))$ that can be described using
$$
\begin{align}
mn(i)&=\lfloor\tfrac12(\sqrt{1+8i}-1)\rfloor\\
m(i)&=i-T(mn(i))\\
n(i)&=mn(i)-m(i)
\end{align}
$$
which seems to be confirmed for $i=0,...,14$ by the following [Wolfram|Alpha-computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%5Bi-floor%281%2F2*%28sqrt%281%2B8i%29-1%29%29%28floor%281%2F2*%28sqrt%281%2B8i%29-1%29%29%2B1%29%2F2%2Cfloor%281%2F2*%28sqrt%281%2B8i%29-1%29%29-%28i-floor%281%2F2*%28sqrt%281%2B8i%29-1%29%29%28floor%281%2F2*%28sqrt%281%2B8i%29-1%29%29%2B1%29%2F2%29%5D%20for%20i%3D0%20to%2014).

Comment: So $J$ is in fact a bijection?

Comment: @user42912: Yes, it is! I added a diagram with $(m,n)=(2,3)$ to show an example of how it works ...

Answer (score 4):

The $k^{th}$ downward diagonal runs from $(k,0)$ to $(0,k)$ and traverses $k+1$ points. So the indices of the points on the vertical axis are $0,1,3,6\dots=0,0+1,0+1+2,0+1+2+3\cdots$, i.e. the triangular numbers $\frac12k(k+1)$.

To get to a point $(m,n)$, you move $m$ steps along the diagonal $k=m+n$, so that the index of this point is $\frac12k(k+1)+m=\frac12(n+m)(n+m+1)+m$.

Comment: I think my answer says the same, but yours is more directly to the point. (+1) for that.

Comment: @String: +1 for this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, J(m,n) gives you the number at coordinates (m,n).
If you try the J(m,n) formula with a few sample values for (m,n) e.g. (3,0), (2,1), you will see it's quite obvious. If you want to really prove it, maybe you can try induction. Or, you can consider the fact that on the N-th diagonal (these with the arrows), you have exactly (N+1) numbers, and then construct the formula yourself.

Comment: I would like to have an intuition why $J$ gives me the number of coordinates of $(m, n)$. I've already tried to understand this formula with sample values for $(m, n)$ without success.

Comment: Think this way: first find a formula for the numbers on the y axis ( it's $n(n+1)/2)$ or say $y(y+1)/2$ ) (in my notation n is y, m is x). Then it's easy, you know the starting point (the one on the y axis), you start from it and follow the diagonal downwards, while doing so y decreases, x increases.