# How do you create the equation for the Cantor Pairing Function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), here is the equation:

$f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y$

How do you go about creating this function? I understand that the X value is found by the corresponding triangle number $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. The Y value is dependant on the diagonal it's in but I'm not quite sure how that's inputted in the equation.

Really simple explainations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is very similar to what I answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217415/94971). Other answers can be found there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangular number function is being shifted both horizontally and vertically by the $y$ input. Thus for any triangular number, you fill in the the diagonal with the subsequent numbers up to the next triangular number.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I can visualize what you're saying. What part of the equation is the "fill in the diagonal" part?

Comment: From $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$, adding $y$ to each $x$ shifts the function horizontally with respect to $y$, and adding the $y$ to the end shifts the function vertically. A shift by one in both directions results in a diagonal.

Comment: Oh now I understand! When you add Y to X, you're actually shifting to the left by Y steps. Then you add Y to the end which shifts it up Y steps. For some reason I kept thinking X+Y was shifting it right. Thanks a lot for your help!